# I have a table that displays records, with each row having 2 buttons on the right most side. How can I get the values of the table in the right order?

Tags: php, html

I have a(n) SQL table with the values Applicationid, username, first_Name, last_Name, and email. I want the records to be displayed on to a table along with 2 buttons (Accept and Reject, which is in 1 table data cell). I am able to display the records and the buttons, however whenever I press any of the buttons, I always get the values of whichever record was entered last.

What I was trying to do in my code was to put the id's into an array, use session, and pass them over to their respective php files. However, I just realized that there's no way for the code to know which button was pressed.

```
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                             <?php
                               while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($applicationResult)){ ?>    
                      <td><?php echo $row['FirstName'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['LastName'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['UserName'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['Email'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['ApplicationID'];?></td>
                      <td><a href="acceptApplication.php" class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-success" name="acceptButton">Accept</button>
                      <a href="rejectApplication.php" class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-danger" name="rejectButton">Reject</button></td>
                        </tr>
                         <?php
                           array_push($applyID, $row['ApplicationID']);  }; ?>
                         </td>
<?php $convApplyID = implode(" ",$applyID); $_SESSION['applicants'] = $convApplyID; echo $convApplyID; // testing yung echo, remove in final code
                                 ?> 
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
```

Is there a way to get the values of the record that the button aligns with?

Comment: You need to pass something in the query string, probably the `Applicationid`

Comment: @ChrisHaas yep, but I am unable to Identify how to get the correct ApplicationID since the code is just giving me the most recent ID that's inserted

Comment: fyi, your `<a>`s are ending in `</button>`. There's a lonely lonely `</td>` after `array_push`

Comment: `$row['ApplicationID']` seems to be the Applicationid?!

Comment: @brombeer Thanks for noticing, the anchors were originally buttons, but I changed it to an anchor but forgot to change the closing bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons don't pass any information with them. The acceptApplication or rejectApplication scripts need to know which application they are processing. The simplest way is to pass a GET request. It should look like this:

```
<tbody>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($applicationResult)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['LastName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['UserName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ApplicationID']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="acceptApplication.php?id=<?php echo $row['ApplicationID']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-success">Accept</a>
            <a href="rejectApplication.php?id=<?php echo $row['ApplicationID']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-danger">Reject</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

If you don't want to use a GET request (as they are stored publicly in the URL) you can use a form to pass a POST request to the respective script. That should look like this:

```
<tbody>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($applicationResult)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['LastName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['UserName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ApplicationID']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <form action="acceptApplication.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="applicationId" value="<?php echo $row['ApplicationID']; ?>">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-success" value="Accept">
            </form>
            <form action="rejectApplication.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="applicationId" value="<?php echo $row['ApplicationID']; ?>">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-danger" value="Reject">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Another way you can pass your request securely is using AJAX. That would look something like this:

HTML:

```
<tbody>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($applicationResult)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['LastName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['UserName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ApplicationID']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="processApplication(<?php echo $row['ApplicationID']; ?>, 'accept')" class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-success">Accept</button>
            <button onclick="processApplication(<?php echo $row['ApplicationID']; ?>, 'reject')" class="btn btn-sm round btn-outline-danger">Reject</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</tbody>
<script>
function processApplication(applicationId, action) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'processApplication.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            // Handle the response here
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    }

    xhr.send("applicationId=" + applicationId + "&action=" + action);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much! I decided to opt to use the 1st or 2nd way, thank you very much. I didn't know you could store/pass data like that!

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors in there - your buttons start with `<a>` and end in `</button>` which is going to complicate things.

You may not need to use session data - instead, what I would do is make the buttons both `<a>` tags and add the data to the `href` attribute as GET params:

```
acceptApplication.php?key=value&key2=value2
```

This will make the data available on the next page in the `$_GET` var.

The data will be visible in the address bar and on hover-over, though, so if you need the data to be non-public, then you can wrap each row in a `form` and use POST to submit the data to the next page as an action which gets you `$_POST` variables on the other page.

See also:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php